# ANTLR lexer error: no viable alternative at character '\n'

Tags: antlr, lexer

I am writing an ANTLR parser that attempts to recognize GDB backtrace output from a given input string.

I'm ignoring new lines with the following lexer grammar:

```
RETURN : ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') { skip(); };
```

However, when I run the parser against some input, ANTLR gives the following lexer error:

```
line 20:21 no viable alternative at character '\n'
line 23:14 no viable alternative at character '\n'
line 30:21 no viable alternative at character '\n'
line 33:31 no viable alternative at character '\n'
```

I am not sure why this would ever happen, since I have already specified '\n' in the lexer.

Does anybody has any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is elsewhere in your grammar: it is still lexing a different element  that has not yet ended, and unexpectedly encountered the end of line while it was still expecting to finish the current element.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the reason. I have a lexer rule `FILE_NAME : (ALPHA | NUMBER | UNDERSCORE | SLASH | DOT)+ DOT (ALPHA | NUMBER)+;` and for a line like "A line.", the error message appears. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: FILE_NAME should probably (possibly) be a parser rule rather than a lexer rule. I'm very much a novice though.